# How to wait till POST request is finished in GO?

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose

Hi I am creating a POST request in GO but it terminates before actually finishing, for example I am trying to pull a docker image and this can be done with curl by the following:

```
curl -X POST https://address/images/create?fromImage=imagename
```

this returns the following

```
{"status":"Pulling from imagename","id":"latest"}
{"status":"Already exists","progressDetail":{},"id":"3d30e94188f7"}
{"status":"Already exists","progressDetail":{},"id":"bf4e27765153"}
{"status":"Already exists","progressDetail":{},"id":"67280fd39fba"}
.... many of those
{"status":"Pull complete","progressDetail":{},"id":"21c062e2346f"}
{"status":"Digest: sha256:24f26a1344fca6d5ee1adcdsf2d01b20d7823c560ed9d2193466e36bd1f049088"}
{"status":"Pulling from imagename","id":"20161005"}
{"status":"Digest: sha256:f527dsfds88676eb25d8f7de5406f46cbc3a995345ddb4bb3d08fcf110458fe3cf"}
{"status":"Status: Downloaded newer image for imagename"}
```

and the image is pulled successfully

but If I try from go

```
func PullImage(imagename string, uuid string) error {
logFields := log.Fields{

    "handler": "PullImage",
    "uuid":    uuid,
}

log.WithFields(logFields).Debugf("imagename:%v", imagename)

url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/images/create?fromImage%s", sconf.Docker.Endpoint, imagename)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)

req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
resp, err := client.Do(req)

log.WithFields(logFields).Infof("call url:%s", url)
if err != nil {
    log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("Error in call url (%s) :%s", url, err)

    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Error in call url (%s) :%s", url, err))
}


var pullresbody interface{}
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&pullresbody)
if err != nil {
    log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("Could not unmarshal json: %s", err)
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Could not unmarshal json: %s", err))
}

    log.WithFields(logFields).Infof("response of url %s:%+v", url, resp)
log.WithFields(logFields).Infof("response body:%+v", pullresbody)
   return nil
```

}

then I get this in the logs:

```
map[status:Pulling from imagename]
```

and the image is not pulled so the connection is stopped before really finishing how can I fix this?

Comment: try reading the entire body of the response with `ioutil.ReadAll`, and then decode the JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Decoder` will only decode one object from a stream at a time. To get all objects, you'll need something like

```
var pullRespBody interface{}
dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
var err error
for err == nil {
    err = dec.Decode(&pullRespBody)
    // Check err...
    log.WithFields(logFields).Infof("response body:%+v", pullRespBody)
    // Do something else with pullRespBody...
}
// Deal with err...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait till the EOF is reached while parsing the data. Ideally you should use the [docker client sdk](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/#pull-an-image-with-authentication) but in case that doesnt help as i am using an internal artifactory it need to send the request via local unix socket.
Refer below code for reference. Change it accordingly to your usecase.

```
type DockerPullData struct {
    Id     string 
    Status string 
    Digest string 
}

func PullDockerImages(url string, target *DockerPullData, header map[string]string) {

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
    req.Header.Set("accept", "application/json;")
    for k, v := range header {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
        req.Header.Set(k, v)
    }

    defaultTransport, ok := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
    if !ok {
        panic("http.DefaultTransport is not a *http.Transport")
    }
    unixTransport := defaultTransport.Clone()
    defaultDialContext := unixTransport.DialContext
    unixTransport.DialContext = func(ctx context.Context, _, _ string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return defaultDialContext(ctx, "unix", "/var/run/docker.sock")
    }

    client := &http.Client{Transport: unixTransport}
    response, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    dec := json.NewDecoder(response.Body)

    var output map[string]interface{}
    for err != io.EOF {
        err = dec.Decode(&output)

        fmt.Printf("Output : %v\n", output)
        target.Id = output["id"].(string)

        // Parse status
        statuskey := output["status"].(string)
        statusValue := strings.SplitN(statuskey, ":", 2)
        if statusValue[0] == "Status" {
            target.Status = statusValue[1]
        }
        if statusValue[0] == "Digest" {
            target.Digest = statusValue[1]
        }

    }
    fmt.Printf("Status :- %s\n", target.Status)
    fmt.Printf("Digest :- %s\n", target.Digest)

}
```